# SPARQL. Give value to result that has no value

Tags: sparql

I tried to find all charities organizations and their country. As you can guess, some organizatins do not belong to any country so their country field is null. I would like to give them a value like "World wide". Can I do it in SPARQL?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the [COALESCE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) function.